# PHP does not find Phpstream class (using namespaces and php 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.3)

Tags: php, http, namespaces, zend-framework2, pear

I installed the pear2 HTTP library using composer, unfortunately I get an error when the library is used (by doctrine, but that should not matter)

```
h@dev0 ~/Repositories/pfo $ vendor/bin/doctrine-module migrations:migrate
# A few statements before the error I included a statement to get the include path: echo ini_get('include_path');
/home/h/Repositories/pfo/vendor/pear-pear2.php.net/PEAR2_Text_Markdown:/home/h/Repositories/pfo/vendor/pear-pear2.php.net/PEAR2_HTTP_Request:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear

# Afterwards I get this error:
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'pear2\HTTP\Request\Adapter\Phpstream' not found in /home/h/Repositories/pfo/vendor/pear-pear2.php.net/PEAR2_HTTP_Request/pear2/HTTP/Request.php on line 98

# And the Phpstream.php does exist, it begins like this:
namespace pear2\HTTP\Request\Adapter;
use pear2\HTTP\Request;
class PhpStream extends Request\Adapter { ... }

# and is located here:
h@dev0 ~/Repositories/pfo $ ls /home/h/Repositories/pfo/vendor/pear-pear2.php.net/PEAR2_HTTP_Request/pear2/HTTP/Request/Adapter/
Curl.php  Filesystem.php  Http.php  Phpsocket.php  Phpstream.php

# The Request.php class looks like this, notice that this file is in a folder together with the Request folder for the 'Request\Adapter\Phpstream' class:
namespace pear2\HTTP;

class Request  {
    ....
    public function __construct($url = null, $instance = null)  {
        echo ini_get('include_path');
        ...
        $this->adapter = new Request\Adapter\Phpstream;
        ...
    }
}
```

These classes are pear2 libraries and hence I strongly wish not to change them. Is there anything I am missing? Why can't php find the class Phpstream? Does the fact that there is a 'Request' folder and 'Request.php' file make things difficult? The doctrine class loader uses the zend framework class loader, but I am not sure what the impact of that is.

Comment: I solved this, I needed to append 'extension=http.so' to /etc/php5/cli/php.ini. I already did so for apache2, but not for the cli (which are different on ubuntu). Did that, and now it works :)

Comment: I also needed to do sudo pecl install -f pecl_http-1.7.6 to have the old API.